# What is reason (CPU, memory or hard disk) that cause my Ubuntu machine slow?

Tags: vmware, docker

I am running docker on a virtual Ubuntu 18.04 server (provided by a VMware Virtual Platform).  Sometimes when I run `docker stats`, it updates very slow (the result show dashes instead of containers info, example in following images [slow0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0tsz.png) [slow1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhBSl.png)). When I type a command in a terminal, it is slow too.

I tried htop, the slow server has a lot of CPU and memory remaining (example [htop0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw5kw.png)).
I tried iotop, the slow server's disk IO is not greater than another normal server.
What can I do to determine why the server is slow?

Comment: Ubuntu 18 server? so do you mean a Ubuntu Core 18 system?? (which is designed for *headless* server use).   Ubuntu uses the *yy* or *year* format for all *snap* only releases; which are different products to the normal *year.month* or *yy.mm* format *deb* based systems.  Please clarify.

Comment: @guiverc I mean Ubuntu version 18.04 (bionic)

Comment: Please correct your question then, as Ubuntu has used the *yy* format to mean different products since 2016 (introduction of Ubuntu Core 16 for appliance/device & cloud use).